# Display data on mainActivity when data mysql db changes

Tags: android, json

The main purpose of this app is to login and display stored data from mysql and display it. well I've done that which works perfectly well. What I need now is for the app to display results for any update or changes in the sql table automatically on my mainActivity.

package com.dedykuncoro.login;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_logout;
    TextView txt_id, txt_username,txt_t_data;
    String id, username, t_data;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String TAG_t_data = "t_data";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
        txt_username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        txt_t_data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_t_data);
        btn_logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Login.my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        id = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
        username = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_USERNAME);
        t_data = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_t_data);

        txt_id.setText("ID : " + id);
        txt_username.setText("USERNAME : " + username);
        txt_t_data.setText("Data Used : " + t_data);

        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // update login session ke FALSE dan mengosongkan nilai id dan username
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Login.session_status, false);
                editor.putString(TAG_ID, null);
                editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, null);
                editor.putString(TAG_t_data, null);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**CODE FOR FETCHING DATA FROM MYSQL IS**

class usr{}

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if ((empty($username)) || (empty($password))) { 
    $response = new usr();
    $response->success = 0;
    $response->message = "This Column Cannot Be Empty"; 
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radcheck WHERE username='$username' AND value='$password'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if (!empty($row)){
    $response = new usr();
    $response->success = 1;
    $response->message = "Welcome ".$row['username'];
    $response->id = $row['id'];
    $response->username = $row['username'];
$query_dused="SELECT radusergroup.username,sum((radacct.acctinputoctets+radacct.acctoutputoctets)) AS T_Data, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,radacct.acctstarttime, radacct.acctstoptime)) AS timeUsed, radusergroup.groupname AS Profile From radacct LEFT JOIN radusergroup ON radusergroup.username=radacct.username WHERE radusergroup.username='$username'"; $d_used = mysql_query($query_dused);while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($d_used, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {$response->t_data = round(($line['T_Data']/1000000000), 2);$response->t_profile= $line['Profile'];$response->t_time= date("H:i:s",$line['timeUsed']);}die(json_encode($response));} else {$response = new usr(); $response->success = 0;$response->message = "Invalid Username or Password";die(json_encode($response));}mysql_close();?>
```

Comment: Show code where you are fetching data from database?

Comment: @PrakashS, please the code has been edited please review it